# Open Module Url in DotNetNuke?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am trying to open a module popup which binds, but it shows an error. The code I'm using is:

```cs
protected void grdStudentAttendanceList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ViewStudent")
    {
        lbntSurnnameClick(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }
}

void lbntSurnnameClick(string StudentID)
{
    string url = UrlUtils.PopUpUrl(EditUrl("StudentID", StudentID, "AddOrUpdateStudent"), this, PortalSettings,true,false, 390, 670);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

It shows this error:

> potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

So, how can I open the module according to `studentID` from a data grid?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a response.redirect to a popup URL.

The PopUp url has some javascript in it and isn't just a regular URL.

Your better option would be to use a HyperLink in your student attendance list and simply set the NavigateUrl to that of your PopUrl on ItemDataBound!